# Perl and Foreach loop with Splitting

Tags: arrays, perl, split

I have a Problem about the Foreach Loop and Splitting with Perl.

I want to loop the Arrays and split it to name and value.

1.) I read the File and save to an String.

2.) I split the empty line and save to an Array.

My Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $pathconfigfile = 'config.conf';
my @configline;

open(my $configfile, "<", $pathconfigfile);

local $/;
my @configdata  = split("\n\n",<$configfile>);

#print $configdata[0], "\n";
#print $configdata[1], "\n";
#print $configdata[2], "\n";

foreach my $data (@configdata){
        my @editing = split /#/, $data;
        my ($name, $value) = @editing[0,1];
        print $name "\n";
        print $value "\n";
}

close $configfile;
```

**Configfile:**

```
Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt
############################################
0987654345678909876MN09uz6t56789oiuhgölkjhgfr
0987654323456789098765fgnloiuztlkjhgfrtzuiknb

MegaMixoiuzt
############################################
09876543457890098765NSUDlkjhzgtfr67899ztz9098
098765435678987t87656789876567898765679097658

TESTINGPARTS
############################################
0987654567890098765hzzasza654567uhgdjdjfacdaa
9876545678987654mchfuiaq754567898765434567876
```

**My wish result:**

$name = Testingtttttttttttttttttttttttt

$value = 0987654345678909876MN09uz6t56789oiuhgölkjhgfr
0987654323456789098765fgnloiuztlkjhgfrtzuiknb

$name = MegaMixoiuzt

$value = 09876543457890098765NSUDlkjhzgtfr67899ztz9098
098765435678987t8765678987656789876567909765

$name = TESTINGPARTS

$value = 0987654567890098765hzzasza654567uhgdjdjfacdaa
9876545678987654mchfuiaq754567898765434567876

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 split /#/          # A "#" separates the two.
```

should be

```
 split /\n#+\n/     # A line of "#" separates the two.
```

---

With other improvements:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $config_qfn = 'config.conf';

open(my $config_fh, "<", $config_qfn )
    or die("Can't open \"$config_qfn\": $!\n");

local $/ = "";  # Paragraph mode
while (my $rec = <$config_fh>) {
    my ($name, $value) = split(/\n#+\n/, $rec);
    print "\$name = $name\n";
    print "\$value = $value\n";
}
```

Comment: perhaps `$data` should not be there

Answer (score 2):

Also something like this without foreach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<config.conf' or die "$!"; my $data = join '', <$fh>; close $fh;
my %hash = $data =~ /^(.+)\n#+\n(\S+\n\S+)/mg;
print "NAME: $_\nVALUE: $hash{$_}\n\n" for keys %hash
```

Comment: Note: This assumes that the value doesn't contain any whitespace characters. It also assumes that the name is exactly one line long, and that the value is always exactly two lines long.

Comment: Thank you! Will `$_ =~ s/\n// for keys %hash` help if necessary? Or I can't understand you?

Comment: I'm not saying there's a problem. I'm just listing the assumptions you've made. They could be perfectly fine assumptions. It's up to the OP to decide. (That said, I don't think the value will always be two-lines long.) That line doesn't affect the assumptions I listed.

Answer (score 1):

You want to split by multiple `#` so use `#+`

`+` match one or more times.

Try it

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $pathconfigfile = 'config.conf';
my @configline;

open(my $configfile, "<", $pathconfigfile);

local $/;
my @configdata  = split("\n\n",<$configfile>);


foreach my $data (@configdata){
    my ($name,$value) = split /\n#+\n/, $data;
    print "$name $value\n\n";
}
```

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for your use full comment. I remove the trailing and leading newline by splitting.  And then i changed the `@value`  to `$value`. :)